# angular - how are these two .factory different

Tags: angularjs

```
sellingApp.factory('SellingService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        Status: Status

    };
    function Status() {
        console.log(breeze);
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Services/Status',
            params: {}
        }).then(function (result) { return result.data; })
        .catch(function (s) { console.log(s); });
    }
}]);


sellingApp.factory("demoFac", ['$http', function ($http) {
    var obj = {};

    obj.fetchUserDetails = function () {
        return $http.get('/Services/Status');
    }

    return obj;
}]);
```

---

the two controllers i've created to impliment each of these "factories" is like this:  I'm trying to see how they differ and which is better.  (neither seem to work - they both return "system.generic.list" instead of data!!!

```
sellingApp.controller('sellingListCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$location', 'breeze','Service',
    function sellingListCtrl($scope, $location, breeze, Service) {
        $scope.init = function () {
            Service.Status().then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
        $scope.init();
    }
]);



sellingApp.controller('sellingListCtrl2', function ($scope, demoFac) {
    demoFac.fetchUserDetails().success(function (response) {
        $scope.lists = response;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serialize your C# list to JSON so angular can process it.
you can use Newtonsoft.Json
`return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object)`

Comment: ok, thanks that works perfectly, but now it just returns a json list when i do a td with ng repeat  item in lists...  I get long string with value and key in quotes.

Comment: not sure what your data looks like but you can get the values by referencing `item[key]`

Comment: that works.  the problem with the json return was because i had included track by $index in the html as someone on a different post said to do.

Answer (score 0):

`system.generic.list` is not an Angular or JavaScript error.  Would most likely be coming from your back-end/api, meaning there's nothing wrong with your controllers/factories.

Comment: when i step through my c#, the values are there. what could it be?  Do I have to return it in Json?

Comment: @LisaSolomon - Yes, you would return the list in JSON.

Comment: is it bad that i am doing it in c# and not breeze?  in breeze it auto serializes, right?

Comment: can i do a stored procedure w/ breeze

Comment: Not familiar with c# or breeze, MB's answer above seems to be an option.